# get record from the reference table Eloquent Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

First, In my mysql database, I have 2 tables named "users" and "users_details" and they are in relationship

users table

> id (PK, AI, INT), username (VARCHAR, UNQ), password (VARCHAR),
>   fullname (VARCHAR)

and the users_table

> id (PK, AI, INT), email (VARCHAR), phone (VARCHAR), address (VARCHAR), has_record (VARCHAR),
>   user_id (int, FK = reference table 'users.id')

and my model bindings.

'User' model

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function user_details(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\users_details');
    }

}
```

and the 'users_details' model

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class users_details extends Model {

    protected $table = "user_details";


       public function ud()
       {
           return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
       }
}
```

and I know I can just do like

```
$data = User::find(1)->with('user_details'); //or
$data = User::find(1)->user_details;
```

but how about I want to get the fullname record from the 'User' table which is the main reference table for the 'users_table' 'user_id' foreign key? how to do it? I tried

```
$data = users_details::where('has_record', '=', 'no')->with('ud')->get(); //get all the records where column 'has_record' of 'users_details' is equal to 'no'
$data = $data->ud->fullname; //get the fullname
```

but unfortunately and sadly not working, any help, ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations please?

UPDATE:

I achieved it using Query builder

```
$test = DB::table('users')
                ->join('user_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_details.user_id')
                ->where('has_record', '=', 'no')
                ->get();
```

but is there a way I could do it using the power of Eloquent?

Comment: Unless there is specific reason not to, I'd suggest putting everything inside the `users` table.  The only reason I could think of to have a `details` table would be if other things besides users had details which could go in there.  As it stands, you are just making things more complicated for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do like that.

According to your code

Find one user detail with user eager load and get name.

```
$user_detail = user_details::with('ud')->find(1);
$user_detail->ud->name;
```

Get all user detail with user eager load and get user name.

```
$user_details = user_details::with('ud')->get();

foreach($user_details as $user_detail){
   echo $user_detail->user->name;
}
```

I have a suggestion for you if you want.
Try to follow the singular/plural format which can make the code more readable.

```
// User Classs.
public function user_detail(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserDetail');
}

// UserDetail Class.
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```